# How to write vertical fractions in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

Does anyone know how to write vertical fractions in MS Word? In running text that is

I can see a way using the *Insert* Equation function but then you have to go out of your text, type the fraction, and then it's off to the side rather than in the running text

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you get that *it's off to the side rather than in the running text*. Equations will be inserted **inline** if there are texts before them. Just

- type the sentence as normal, and at the point you want to insert the equation don't press enter, just insert the equation with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>)
- then enter the equation using the slash format like a/b
- press <kbd>Space</kbd>

The last step is important. MS Equation will automatically convert the slash to the fraction after you type a space. For example typing `(a+b)/(b+c)` then <kbd>space</kbd> will create a fraction with `a + b` as the numerator and `b + c` as the denominator **without the parentheses**. Yes it's very smart to remove those parentheses

In fact you can even enter far more complex expressions. For example `a/(b+1)+(a-b)/2-\sqrt(a^2-\sqrt(b))/(b^3-1)` will be converted into the below after the last space

[image]

If you know [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) then you can do even more complicated formatting with it, because MS Equation also supports LaTeX. But that needs a lot more typing for typing simple equations like that

Of course field code also works, but you won't get automatic correct mathematical formatting

Answer (score 0):

From [this tutorial](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CreateFraction.htm):

> The most universally useful way to create ad hoc fractions is with the EQ (Equation) field using the `\f` switch. This creates a fraction with a horizontal line between the numerator and the denominator. Here’s how to do it:
>
> 1. Place the insertion point where you want the fraction to appear.
> 2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd> to insert field braces.
> 3. Between the field braces, type the following:
>
>    ```
>    EQ \F(a,b)
>    ```
>
>    where a and b are the numerator and denominator of the fraction. For example, if you want to create the fraction 1/16, the field would look like this:
>
>    ```
>    { EQ \F(1,16) }
>    ```
> 4. With the insertion point in the field, press <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>.